# Synchronizing local database with remote database and vice versa

Tags: java, php, mysql, sql

I am developing a web application with php that needs to synchronize a local mysql database that a java desktop version of the web application is interacting with. At the same time i also need the local db to synchronize with the remote db. How do i do this without using other software like MySQL Compare. I will really appreciate the help. Thanx guys.

Comment: MySQL replication could help: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html

Answer (score 0):

You clearly have a significant architecture issue. It needs to be planned very well. Two-way replication clearly isn't going to work unless you have thought it out very carefully and understand how to do conflict resolution and what impact that will have on your application. In particular, you can forget using AUTO_INCREMENT.

For one-way replication, you can use mk-table-sync, or use mysql replication in some way (there are a variety of possiblities).

You can also run another mysql instance on the server, use mk-table-sync to periodically synchronise it locally, and use mysql replication on that. This has some benefits, particularly if there are some tables you don't want to replicate.

You really need to think about how it's going to work, if you plan to do two-way synchronisation. It is possible that you may end up writing custom code to do it, as the conflict resolution mechanism may mandate it.